# Css positioning with using percentage

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am a newbie and I want to have a webpage exactly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP5i4.jpg) picture. 
However, I also want to make divs' height and width with percentage not px's.

When I try that, boxes either come out on top of each other or they do not even occur. Because my logic is working like below.

For example:

1. Wrapper `position:absolute;` `height:100%;` `width:100%;` (If I make it with px, no problem but when I try it with percentage then usually I can not get a wrapper, why?)
2. header `position:relative` (which means relative to wrapper?) `height:10%;` `width:100%;`
3. slider `position:relative;` `height:70%;` `width;100%;` `top:10%`(why? because 10% is used by header, therefore it should start 10% below??)
   ...etc
   ...
4. footer `position: relative;` `height:10%;` `width:100%;` `bottom:0;` (It must fit to the bottom)

I hope I can tell my problem clearly.
Shortly, can anyone help me with absolute and relative positioning via my example?

```css
 #wrapper{
 background-color:red;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
  }
 
#header{
 background-color:yellow;
 height:20%;
 width:100%;
 position: relative;

 
 }
 
#slider{
 background-color:blue;
 position: relative;
 height:70%;
 width:100%;
 top:20%;
 
 }
 
#footer{
 background-color:yellow;
 position:relative;
 height:10%;
 width:100%;
 top:90%;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="slider"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the html code, that could help.

Comment: Do you understand what absolute and relative positioning mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a copy of your markup, with updated CSS to have a 20% header, 70% slider and 10% footer.

The inner `div`'s is `position: relative` and as such, you don't need to set any `top`, they automatically stack after each other, and there's no need to set `width` either as their default is full width (as 100%).

When use `position: absolute` though, as with the `wrapper`, one need to set `left`, `top`, `width` and `height`.

```css
htmml, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; }

#wrapper{
  background-color:red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:20%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#slider{
  background-color:blue;
  position: relative;
  height:70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#footer{
  background-color:yellow;
  position:relative;
  height:10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="slider"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a more modern way, using `flex`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  flex: 0;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  flex: 0;
  flex-basis: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <main>
    Slider
  </main>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a good and useful code, thanks but my main concern is using positioning with divs (div in divs etc..).. I edited my question and added my simple code.

Comment: @AApro Updated my answer